# How to format the answer line

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

I have to make code that matches the X and Y values of specific drawing made of circular path and linear path all put together. I was able to put a good code that works fine and is acceptable however two values of Y are long, and I would like to either round it or somehow make it like a whole number like an int, but I tried many ways but don't understand where to put the code and how, I tried many things to convert it but never was able to output these 2 values of Y as a whole because I have to use int or the format does not work, and the result kind of makes it unprofessional, it works and is enough, but I want to go the extra mile and make it a whole number, so it looks better here is the result of my two values that I'm talking about.

```
Using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double Xmin = -9, Xmax = 9, dX = 2, T = 2, Y;
            Console.WriteLine("|   X    |   Y    |");
            for ( double X = Xmin; X <= Xmax; X += dX )
            {
                Y = T;
                if (X >= -9 && X <= -6) Y = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(3, 2) - Math.Pow(X + 6, 2));
                if (X >= -6 && X <= -3) Y = X + 3;
                if (X >= -3 && X <=  0) Y = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(3, 2) - Math.Pow(X, 2));
                if (X >=  0 && X <=  3) Y = X - 3;
                if (X >=  3 && X <=  9) Y = 0.5 * X - 1.5;
                Console.WriteLine("| {0,6} | {1,6} |", X, Y);
            }
           Console.ReadKey();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like most of this isn't relevant. You have two variables, X and Y, and you want to format them with a specified number of decimal places. Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Comment: Also, this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-6.0#how-do-i-control-the-number-of-integral-digits has other common questions about the `String.Format`-like formatting used by `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: thank you guys you solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, but you lost accuracy

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ConsoleApp7
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                double Xmin = -9, Xmax = 9, dX = 2, T = 2, Y;
                Console.WriteLine("|   X    |   Y    |");
                for ( double X = Xmin; X <= Xmax; X += dX )
                {
                    Y = T;
                    if (X >= -9 && X <= -6) Y = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(3, 2) - Math.Pow(X + 6, 2));
                    if (X >= -6 && X <= -3) Y = X + 3;
                    if (X >= -3 && X <=  0) Y = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(3, 2) - Math.Pow(X, 2));
                    if (X >=  0 && X <=  3) Y = X - 3;
                    if (X >=  3 && X <=  9) Y = 0.5 * X - 1.5;
                    Console.WriteLine("| {0,6} | {1,6} |", Math.Round(X, 4), Math.Round(Y, 4));
                   
                }
               Console.ReadKey();
            } 
        }
    }
```